# How to toggle and hide two different forms in the same section

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, events

Kindly help with is:
I wanted to have two forms in a section, if a button is clicked the first form will be visible and if the second button is clicked the second form will be visible while the first form is hidden, this will be on the same section. How do I achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it's nice to include what you have tried so far, and maybe a little bit of the code that you are working with but I will try my best to help you anyway.

I used an article from dyn-web.com found [here](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/radio/onclick.php#:%7E:text=When%20a%20radio%20button%20is,total%20field%20of%20the%20form.) which allows you to assign `onClick` handlers to the pair of radio buttons. I then simply adapted the handlers to show and hide the respective forms.

I've commented the parts of the code that you would change to add your own form in but for the moment there is just a test input and submit button for each form.

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function switchForms() {
      var sz = document.forms['formSelector'].elements['form'];

      // loop through list
      
      for (var i=0, len=sz.length; i<len; i++) {
        sz[i].onclick = function() { // assign onclick handler  function to each
          // change the 'display' style property of the forms to show and hide them
          var display;
          var dntDisplay;
          if (this.value == 1) {
            display = 1;
            dntDisplay = 2;
          }else{
            display = 2;
            dntDisplay = 1;
          }
          document.getElementById('form' + display).style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('form' + dntDisplay).style.display = "none";
        };
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="switchForms()">

  <form action="#" method="post" class="formSelector" id="formSelector">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Change form on-click</legend>    
      <p>Select your form:&nbsp;
        <label><input type="radio" name="form" value="1" checked="checked" /> Form 1</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="form" value="2"  /> Form 2</label>
      </p>
    </fieldset><br>
  </form>
    
  <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <h2>Form 1</h2>
    <!-- Insert any input fields you want for form 1 here -->
    <label>Input: <input type="text" name="total" class="num" value="" /></label>
    <button name="sbt=form1" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
    
  <form id="form2" method="post" style="display:none" action="">
    <h2>Form 2</h2>
    <!-- Insert any input fields you want for form 2 here -->
    <label>Input: <input type="text" name="total" class="num" value="" /></label>
    <button name="sbt-form2" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
    
</body>
```

Comment: Nice one, you are the best